# Node configuration to launch .exe file

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, launch, vscode-debugger

I am trying without success to create a node configuration in order to launch a .exe file that uses some of the files in my project as an argument.

What would be the proper argument setup? At the moment this is what I have:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch my exe",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}/bin/launcher.exe",
        "args": [
            "arg1=${workspaceRoot}",
            "arg2=3",
             "arg3=${workspaceRoot}/bin/lists.xml",
             "arg4 = C:\Programs\lists2.xml"
         ]}
]
}
```

The "Launch my exe" tab appears on the debugger but I am having some parsing errors in the configuration itself and the exe file does not launch.

Anyone with suggestions to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First try to use a newer version of the configuration file (e.g. 2.0.0). Then use the context menu to format your structure to see if braces match etc.

The arguments list looks strange. Does your launcher expect them in that way (e.g. `arg1=`, `arg2=` etc., this is certainly not required for the lauch config)? Manually construct a valid call for your binary and once this works split it up and copy the values to your launch config.